# How to type double quote in the code?

Tags: editors

Before making an answer to this question, please make sure to be aware I'm asking about code editing, not the appearance of PDF file.

When I use tikz-cd, I have to type the double quote mark `"` in my code.
This symbol must be typed in a **single** letter. But When I press the `Shift` + `'` keys, I get the two letters `''` on the editor, which is a wrong result.

I want to accomplish my goal **only by** pressing the `Shift` and the quotation mark key `'` on the keyboard simultaneousely. What can I do for this? Should I modify some options of the editor?

By the way I tried the followings, all of which didn't work:

(1) Typing the single quote mark `'` twice to get `''`.

(2) Typing the single quote opening mark `` ` `` twice to get ``` `` ```.

(3) Typing `Shift`+`'` twice. This is an answer to a very similar question to mine, but all I got was just the `''''`. This answer doesn't work.

Comment: How this is related to (La)TeX? If I understood your question correctly, your problem depends on your editor settings, which is unknown to us.

Comment: Why don't you want to type `Shift` + `"` directly?

Comment: I don't think this is off topic: it appears that Alpaca is using a LaTeX IDE that does automatic substitution, and since discussion of LaTeX IDEs is on topic, we should find out which editor is being used and then I'm sure there's a way to turn off the autocomplete for quotes.

Comment: Alpaca: we can't help you unless you tell us what editor you are using.

Comment: @AlanMunn I didn't even know there are several editors! Thanks for the comment, and I use TeXworks editor.

Comment: _But When I press the Shift + ' keys, I get the two letters `''` on the editor, which is a wrong result._ Isn't it just the auto-closing feature in your editor? The same probably occurs when typing `(`, `"`, as well as `'`. Regardless, as @UlrikeFischer suggested,  what happens if you type `"`, directly?

Comment: What happens if you insert the `"` in a plain text editor, before you open the file in your TeX editor? Does it make a substitution, or leave your typed character as-is?

Comment: Since I don't see this answer in either the comments here or in the linked question/answer, here's what I do on a Linux box: type <ctrl>q and then the double quote " .  (<ctrl>q in this usage means to quote the following character.)

Answer (score 0):

This problem persists in Vim text editor with vim-latex plugin activated.
In this case the solution is:

Add string :

```
let g:Tex_SmartKeyQuote=0
```

to file (create file if doesn't exist) :

```
path_to_your_vim_directory/ftplugin/tex.vim
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Do we know that the OP is actually using Vim as their editor? (You might want to clarify that this is an answer specifically about Vim.)

Comment: What do you mean by *vim*?

Comment: Sorry. This is answer specially for vim, which is text editor and has described problem, when vim-latex suite is used